# Issue JSON parsing illegal(?) characters

Tags: json

I'm getting the following error trying to parse a string with some strange characters:

```
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonResponse);
....
parser.getText();
```

> System.JSONException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing
>   quote for a string value at input location

I believe the value in question contains characters like ÃƒÂ¤, which are supposedly chinese characters in a database. Are these characters supported in Salesforce? If not, is my only real option throwing a try catch around all my "getText()" calls to just set the value to empty string or something?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the full JSON response so people can help you more effectively. I wouldn't expect other characters to cause an issue with strings, it sounds like genuinely malformed JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately it is production level data -- it just happens to work normally and when I find errors I can look back at the source and find a matching strange character in the column that the debug log refers to as the failure.

Comment: Without seeing an actual failing JSON response, it's pretty hard to give you an answer. Everything else in Salesforce can handle unicode characters, so I'd be reasonably surprised if it was just the characters causing it to break

Comment: I'm hoping to get an explicit JSON to take a look at tomorrow - when I manually try to pass over these characters (or update the database to test) it works fine, so to @LaceySnr's point it might be some strange character code that isn't escaped or creates some sort of malformed JSON.

Comment: After doing more debugging, it is actually unescaped ampersands (&) inside the JSON values that is giving that error. I'm leveraging PHP 4.3 to generate this, so I unfortunately can't use json_encode.

Comment: Great - thanks for posting the solution below. Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't a Salesforce issue, so much as it was an issue with the input. I was using PHP to json_encode in a PHP4.3 environment with [JSONWrapper](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html), and the ampersands in the data were not being escaped. Salesforce was trying to parse JSON values with ampersands and treating it as a new parameter. Once I added urlencode($data) within my PHP file prior to sending it to Salesforce it was resolved.

Comment: 4.3?????? :P *hissssss*